# Can you prevent Juju from destroying machines?

Tags: juju, maas

I've been experimenting with Juju and after I deploy a service to a node if I destroy it the node is released from Juju back into the MaaS pool.

From the documentation it doesn't seem like this should happen until the environment or machine is destroyed (juju destroy-machine or juju destroy environment), however it happens as soon as I destroy the only service running on the machine (e.g. juju destroy wordpress). Juju frees the machine and it goes back to the 'Ready' state in MaaS, so deploying a new service requires an eight minute wait.

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to juju but what I do to prevent this is by deploying an [ubuntu](https://jujucharms.com/ubuntu/) charm and then deploying the service on that machine.
So, first we should assign a tag to that node in MAAS UI before deploying ubuntu charm. Then

```
juju deploy ubuntu --constraints tags=<tag that we set>
```

A new node with ubuntu will come up.
Now deploy the service on that machine

```
juju deploy <charm_url> --to <machine_number>
```