# Force JUJU to not remove Machine after removing all charms

Tags: juju, maas

Why juju remove machine after removing all charms?

How can I force juju to not remove machine when I remove all charms from that machine?

Comment: I don't have any relation with Juju :), but common workaround which used for similar issues is to leave a dummy charm (example `dummy sink` or create yours).

Comment: Same question https://askubuntu.com/questions/604131/can-you-prevent-juju-from-destroying-machines Could you try the answer submitted there?